# C++: Comparing strings lexicographical

Tags: c++, string, comparison, lexicographic

Are strings compared lexicographical when using the overriden `bool operator<(const std::string & rhs)` operator? In example:

```
std::string str1 = "aabbcc"
std::string str2 = "bbaacc"

(str1 < str2) == std::lexicographical_compare(str1.begin(),str1.end(),str2.begin(),str2.end()) // is this statement true?
```

Comment: yes they are the same it wouldn't make sense if string comparison was not performed lexographically

Comment: @EdChum: actually, it could make sense. Some locales' comparison isn't lexicographical.

Comment: @jpalecek Hmm, I guess so I tend to always think of these things in western(ASCII) land, cheers for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

String's comparison operators are defined in terms of its `traits::compare` (that is `char_traits<char>::compare`) (C++03 21.3.6.8) which is specified to return a value based on the lexicographical ordering of its arguments (21.1.1).

> X::compare(p,q,n) ...  yields: 0 if for each i in [0,n),
>     X::eq(p[i],q[i]) is true; else, a negative
>     value if, for some j in [0,n),
>     X::lt(p[j],q[j]) is true and for each i in
>     [0,j) X::eq(p[i],q[i]) is true; else a positive value.

In effect, it means comparing string must not be locale sensitive (which could be non-lexicographical in some locales, such as mine).